# Create a boolean column from a long string column. Multi-select question

Tags: regex, pandas, string

I have a column in a dataframe like this. This is a survey questions that allows you to select multiple answers.  What I want is a new column distinguishing a person is native English speaker or not.

A person is a native English speaker when the `english` is not followed by `(fluently)` or anything else.

```
35874    english (fluently), chinese (fluently), spanis...
40792                                              english
39405                                   english (fluently)
51413                                              english
49929    english (fluently), french (fluently), german ...
7147     english (fluently), japanese (poorly), thai (o...
17019                                              english
12321    english (okay), french (fluently), german (poo...
20974    english, sign language (fluently), spanish (po...
6134                                    english (fluently)
43291    english (fluently), german (fluently), french ...
7023     english (fluently), french (poorly), japanese ...
47637         english, french, hawaiian, japanese, spanish
56354    english, spanish (okay), other (fluently), fre...
5094     english (fluently), lisp (okay), japanese (poo...
14654                                              english
37842                                   english (fluently)
11962                                     english, chinese
37021                                              english
30360                                   english (fluently)
43865                                     english, spanish
29744    english (fluently), italian (fluently), spanis...
37088     english (fluently), dutch (okay), spanish (okay)
52986                                              english
59871                                              english
28376                                              english
3973                  english (fluently), spanish (poorly)
46417    english (fluently), spanish (fluently), french...
7986            english (fluently), ancient greek (poorly)
9919                               english, spanish (okay)
```

I tried regex and `split(',',expand=True)` but am still having a hard time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.split(',')` and check if 'English'` is in the list:

```
df2['speaks'] = df2['speaks'].astype(str)
df2['English Native?'] = df2['speaks'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: 'Native' if 'english' in x else 'Not Native')
df2
Out[1]: 
        0                                             speaks  English Native?
0   35874  english (fluently), chinese (fluently), spanis...  Not Native
1   40792                                            english      Native
2   39405                                 english (fluently)  Not Native
3   51413                                            english      Native
4   49929  english (fluently), french (fluently), german ...  Not Native
5    7147  english (fluently), japanese (poorly), thai (o...  Not Native
6   17019                                            english      Native
7   12321  english (okay), french (fluently), german (poo...  Not Native
8   20974  english, sign language (fluently), spanish (po...      Native
9    6134                                 english (fluently)  Not Native
10  43291  english (fluently), german (fluently), french ...  Not Native
11   7023  english (fluently), french (poorly), japanese ...  Not Native
12  47637       english, french, hawaiian, japanese, spanish      Native
13  56354  english, spanish (okay), other (fluently), fre...      Native
14   5094  english (fluently), lisp (okay), japanese (poo...  Not Native
15  14654                                            english      Native
16  37842                                 english (fluently)  Not Native
17  11962                                   english, chinese      Native
18  37021                                            english      Native
19  30360                                 english (fluently)  Not Native
20  43865                                   english, spanish      Native
21  29744  english (fluently), italian (fluently), spanis...  Not Native
22  37088   english (fluently), dutch (okay), spanish (okay)  Not Native
23  52986                                            english      Native
24  59871                                            english      Native
25  28376                                            english      Native
26   3973               english (fluently), spanish (poorly)  Not Native
27  46417  english (fluently), spanish (fluently), french...  Not Native
28   7986         english (fluently), ancient greek (poorly)  Not Native
29   9919                            english, spanish (okay)      Native
```

Comment: Hey I got this error, why? `----> 1 df2['speaks'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: 'Native' if 'english' in x else 'Not Native')

TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable`

Comment: `----> 1 df2['speaks'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: 'Native' if 'english' in x else 'Not Native')  TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable` This one. Your `df[1]` is called `df2['speaks']` on my side

Comment: Thanks! I think you should edit your answer back into `lambda x: 'Native' if 'english' in x else 'Not Native'`. The new one sets 'english (fluently)' as 'Native' as well